# DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString forcefully in other language in android

Tags: android

I am trying implement DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString  in android but i want to show data in italian language even if default language of phone is set to the English 
I want to show data i.e "1 ora fa"  instead of "1 minute ago"

I am using following code for this

```
DateUtils.  getRelativeTimeSpanString (currenttimeMillis, System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS).toString().toLowerCase(Locale.ITALIAN)
```

Comment: And what do you get back?  What is the issue that you are encountering.  Just in case we do not need to do research into the function itself if there is an immediate overlying issue.

Comment: @JaySnayder I am getting "1 minute ago"  if currenttimeMillis is 1 minute ago but instead of this I want a result in italian language

Comment: The call that you have there is returning English text?

Comment: @JaySnayder yes  i want to create forcefully in Italian language even if my  device language is set to the English

Answer (score 0):

Since i don't know how to format the locale of DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString and it will hard to manually change the language that provided by the default user device. I made this method using TimeUnit.

Here i made it simpler for you, just use this method and change the timezone, date format and strings that will be used in your language. If you have any problem or i missed something, let me know.

```
public static String getRelativeTimeSpanString(String time) {
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);//change this format if you don't want to use this format
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+7"));//change this to the timezone you use
        Date datePast = sdf.parse(time);
        Date dateNow = new Date();
        //here you can change the language to match your language
        String sAgo = "yang lalu";
        String sMilli = "mili detik";
        String sSecond = "detik";
        String sMinute = "menit";
        String sHour = "jam";
        String sDay = "hari";
        String sWeek = "minggu";
        String sMonth = "bulan";
        String sYear = "tahun";

        long lDay = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(dateNow.getTime() - datePast.getTime());
        if (lDay == 0) {
            long lHour = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(dateNow.getTime() - datePast.getTime());
            if (lHour == 0) {
                long lMinute = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(dateNow.getTime() - datePast.getTime());
                if (lMinute == 0) {
                    long lSecond = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(dateNow.getTime() - datePast.getTime());
                    if (lSecond == 0) {
                        long lMilliSecond = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(dateNow.getTime() - datePast.getTime());
                        if (lMilliSecond == 0) {
                            return time;
                        } else {
                            return lMilliSecond + " " + sMilli + " " + sAgo;
                        }
                    } else {
                        return lSecond + " " + sSecond + " " + sAgo;
                    }
                } else {
                    return lMinute + " " + sMinute + " " + sAgo;
                }
            } else {
                return lHour + " " + sHour + " " + sAgo;
            }
        } else {
            if (lDay < 7) {
                return lDay + " " + sDay + " " + sAgo;
            } else {
                long lWeek = lDay / 7;
                if (lWeek < 4) {
                    return lWeek + " " + sWeek + " " + sAgo;
                } else if (lWeek == 4) {
                    return 1 + sMonth + " " + sAgo;
                } else {
                    long lMonth = lDay / 30;
                    if (lMonth < 12) {
                        return lMonth + " " + sMonth + " " + sAgo;
                    } else if (lMonth == 12) {
                        return 1 + sYear + " " + sAgo;
                    } else {
                        long lYear = lDay / 365;
                        return lYear + " " + sYear + " " + sAgo;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return time;
    }
}
```

It is possible too to change the configuration's locale with this method

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
private void setDefaultLocale() {
    //call this method from application scope
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration(Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration());
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        configuration.locale = Locale.ENGLISH; // or whichever locale you desire
    } else {
        configuration.setLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
    }
    Resources.getSystem().updateConfiguration(configuration, null);
}
```

But i don't think change the locale a good idea.

Answer (score -1):

I used this method

### code

```
public static String getRelativeTimeSpanString(Context context, Date fromdate) {

long then;
then = fromdate.getTime();
Date date = new Date(then);

StringBuffer dateStr = new StringBuffer();

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

int days = daysBetween(calendar.getTime(), now.getTime());
int weeks= days/7;
int minutes = hoursBetween(calendar.getTime(), now.getTime());
int hours = minutes / 60;
if (days == 0) {

    int second = minuteBetween(calendar.getTime(), now.getTime());
    if (minutes > 60) {
        if (hours >= 1 && hours <= 24) {
            dateStr.append(String.format("%s %s %s",
                    hours,
                    context.getString(R.string.hour)
                    ,context.getString(R.string.ago)));
        }
    }else {
        if (second <= 10) {
            dateStr.append(context.getString(R.string.now));
        } else if (second > 10 && second <= 30) {
            dateStr.append(context.getString(R.string.few_seconds_ago));
        } else if (second > 30 && second <= 60) {
            dateStr.append(String.format("%s %s %s",
                    second,
                    context.getString(R.string.seconds)
                    ,context.getString(R.string.ago)));
        } else if (second >= 60 && minutes <= 60) {
            dateStr.append(String.format("%s %s %s",
                    minutes,
                    context.getString(R.string.minutes)
                    ,context.getString(R.string.ago)));
        }
    }
} else

if (hours > 24 && days < 7) {
    dateStr.append(String.format("%s %s %s",
            days,
            context.getString(R.string.days)
            ,context.getString(R.string.ago)));
}else if(weeks == 1){
    dateStr.append(String.format("%s %s %s",
            weeks,
            context.getString(R.string.weeks)
            ,context.getString(R.string.ago)));
}
else {
    /**
     * make formatted createTime by languageTag("fa")
     *
     * @return
     */
    return SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance(SimpleDateFormat.LONG,new Locale("fra"))
            .format(date).toUpperCase();
}

return dateStr.toString();
}

public static int minuteBetween(Date d1, Date d2) {
return (int) ((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / android.text.format.DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
}

public static int hoursBetween(Date d1, Date d2) {
return (int) ((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / android.text.format.DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS);
}

public static int daysBetween(Date d1, Date d2) {
return (int) ((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / android.text.format.DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS);
}
```

and I set date as a parameter to this method:

```
return getRelativeTimeSpanString(context,this.createdTime);
```

**this return string by location as I wanted!**